# Hanning Window Formula - Matlab didn't work

Tags: matlab, window-functions

I'm trying to do the Hanning Window manually but didn't work, what I'm doing wrong?

```
t=[0:.1:10];
x=.5-.5*cos(2*pi*t/102);
plot(x);
```

[image]

Not sure why I cant obtain the full hanning window..

Comment: I did this `w=hann(100);` and work fine, but I need it do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change "102" to "10".

```
x=.5-.5*cos(2*pi*t/10);
```

Comment: Thanks :), I though it was the number of samples

Comment: @Pulse9 You want the window to start at 0 and end at 0, so that means that the cos must start and end at 1- i.e. it must go through exactly one cycle.

Answer (score 0):

There was a meteorologist (and [Hann window-maker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function)) named [Julius von Hann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_von_Hann) , Hanning is an abuse (similarity with Hamming). You would have a better control of your code calling the `hann.m` or the `window.m` functions:

```
nSample = 101; 
t = linspace(0,10,nSample); 
% w = hann(nSample);
w  = window(@hann,nSample);
% w = .5-.5*cos(2*pi*t/10);
plot(t,w)
```

I hope that implementing it manually does not involve computing cosine with series.

Comment: Why would calling the build in functions be any better? They work internally exactly the same as the manual method and have more layers of checking and parsing which makes them a bit slower. The build in functions specifically use "w = 0.5 - 0.5*cos(2*pi*x);"

Comment: @Hilmar I wrote "better code control", because the function being implemented (a window) is explicit from the call, even without comments. Someone else, or the programmer three month later, will understand  easily what it does, and can change it, improve it right away, without having to guess. Additionally, putting the length (`nSample`) or window name   as variables improve the readability.